# Linux install Problem

Tags: linux, windows-vista, multi-boot

I have Vista opertating system . I want to install Linx Redhat 5 in my Leptop.
I had create parttion in my harddisk.
I want to know at the boot time of **linux where i want to set a path for new drive?**
Is there any link for that ?
Kindly Help in this prob.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Try: http://superuser.com/.

Comment: Better on Super User indeed, but **don't** repost. This question will be migrated by the combined efforts of five high rep users and reposting will create unwanted duplicates...

Comment: could you be more specific. i honestly do not know what your problem is exactly

Comment: I am not sure I quite understand your question. You may look at grub and fstab. Their config files are /boot/grub/grub.conf and /etc/fstab. About fstab: http://fclose.com/p/linux/man/5-fstab/#lbAD

Comment: Are you asking where to set the mount point while installing? Or where to mount (e.g. USB disks)?

Answer (score 3):

Red Hat linux is a serious server OS. 
It is not for noobs!!

seriously - for any kind of local development - just use Ubuntu.

Comment: What's wrong with the RHat desktop distro? http://www.redhat.com/virtualization/rhev/desktop/. I honestly don't know, since I only use Debian and Mint Debian http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_debian.php.

Comment: There is totally nothing bad with Red Hat distro. It's just Red Hat is not exactly a general use OS like Mint/Ubuntu and I really don't see the point in installing something like that on laptop. From his question it feels like this is someone completely new to Linux is trying maybe to learn couple new things.  And for that I would suggest something easier (to begin with) - like Ubuntu/Kubuntu/Mint ..maybe Debian...

Comment: I get your drift, just that I've never used their desktop edition, but had heard good things. (I'm very happy with what I've got!)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are asking where to install Red Hat. You want the mount point to be `/`, unless you are installing inside of Windows. Maybe this will help you out a bit [Understanding Mount Point /mnt](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/manual1/mountpoints.html), but this is easier to understand: [Dual-Boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu in Perfect Harmony](http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual+boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony). The fact that it mentions Ubuntu is irrelevant up until you actually start configuration (i.e. post successful install). Enjoy your partial freedom from M$.